# How do I create an AC electromagnet for a particular type of field generator?

Tags: current, ac, electromagnetism, magnetics, electromagnet

I’m trying to generate a special sort of field in a spherical spinning iron core using two orthogonally oriented coils.

One single-layer coil of 18 AWG magnet wire is wrapped directly onto most of the surface area of the 1” iron sphere that is to be spun, with its direction perpendicular to the spin axis. Some commutators and brushes will be used to deliver direct current to this coil. I’ll refer to this as the rotor of the field generator.

Another single-layer coil of 18 AWG magnet wire is then wrapped onto a fixed hollow spherical shell (not much larger than the rotor, let’s say it has an OD of 1.5”) surrounding the rotor, with its direction parallel to the spin axis. This is the stator.

What is the easiest/simplest/cheapest/most reliable way to go about supplying an alternating current to the stator coil? Getting an exact frequency and amplitude aren’t a concern, as I can simply tune the spin frequency/wattage of the rotor coil to match. But of course ensuring the amplitude is low enough to not damage anything is important.

Comment: Is *direction* along the axis of a coil (of parallel windings?), or along its conductor?

Comment: @greybeard Direction refers to the axis (length) of the coil in relation to the spin axis of the iron sphere.

Comment: So the direction of the length of the rotor coil is perpendicular to the spin axis of the iron sphere (which the coil spins with, since it’s directly attached), and the direction of the length of the stator coil is parallel to the spin axis of the iron sphere.

Answer (score 1):

Simple and reliable should be a transformer from 60 Hz or 50 Hz mains to a pretty low voltage - 18 AWG suggesting not too many turns.
In the old times, I might have picked a 6 V incandescent bulb as a crude current limiter.

Comment: (There was a "trick" not to burden what was to be fed a limited current with the "cold filament current": start with a closed switch parallel to the load, open the switch for turn on.)

Comment: So something like a Variac, right? How should I go about connecting the two ends of the magnet wire to the ‘standard wall outlet’ featured on such variable transformers? I assume I’m not meant to simply scrape the enamel off and shove the two ends into the live/neutral slots…

Comment: `Getting an exact frequency and amplitude aren’t a concern`: I thought of a 5, 6, 6.3 or even 3 V transformer, relying on some sort of series resistance to not overload the stator winding.

Comment: Is that like… a product I can buy off-the-shelf? I’m no electrical engineer.

Comment: When I google “5v ac transformer” I’m met with a gaggle of products that range from wall adapters with barrel plugs, to whacky looking chunks of unidentifiable metal with 5-6 wires poking out. I assume the latter is what I need, but how do I plug the thing into my wall, and then plug the other end of the thing into the coil? And what is “some sort of series resistance” supposed to be? Sorry, I’m very new to all this.

Comment: `chunk of metal with 5 wires poking out` is *exactly* what I'd expect from a web search for a 3 V transformer. One alternative is "xyz V to 3 V AC adapter". The resistance includes the effective secondary series resistance of the transformer, plus may be a power resistor, tens of meters of wire, or above-mentioned light bulb, value depending on what transformer is handy.

Comment: Older doorbells in the US run from transformers with a 24-volt secondary.  You can buy doorbell transformers at any hardware or home improvement store.

Comment: Thanks! I’ll try my best I guess.

Comment: I feel like that came across a bit ungrateful. Upon reading over it all again with more time to do so it is quite a lot of very useful information. Much appreciated, guys.

Comment: (Doorbell transformer is a good idea as these used to be specified to not take damage when shorted even permanently.)

Comment: What about a ZVS driver?

Comment: I think that would be another EE@SE question.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Class-Transformr-120Vac-10Vac-Foot/dp/B00GPOV54U/ref=asc_df_B00GPOV54U/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=241989147482&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=14054118772695043219&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=m&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9004996&hvtargid=pla-465207205374&psc=1

So would this be sufficient? Or overkill? I would just connect the two black wires to the live/neutral wires of a wall plug, and then use the included screws to attach the coil’s wires? A fuse and resistor of some sort ought to be somewhere in the system as well?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B06XRKMYKR?psc=1&ref=ppx_pop_mob_b_asin_image

So for this power supply cord, would it matter which of the two black wires on that doorbell transformer are connected to the black and white wires on the power cord?

Comment: I'm unaware of any use or effect of the fields described: I have no idea about sufficiency or overkill. I have an inkling the field along the axle isn't going to rotate anything. I notice the transformer is rated 10 V, 500 mA.

Comment: I’m trying to generate/study what seems appropriate to call a quadrupolar spin-oscillation field in a single 1” iron sphere. The field generator consists of a DC-fed coil attached directly to the spinning iron sphere that will provide it with a spinning dipole (rotor of the generator), while an AC-fed coil wrapped around a hollow plastic sphere surrounding the rotor will provide an oscillating dipole to it (stator). The two dipoles will combine in the iron sphere and interact in a highly dynamic way. I want to test the effects of this quadrupolar spin-oscillating field on external conductors.

Comment: So I guess “overkill” would mean melting the plastic shell the stator coil is wrapped onto and/or overheating the iron sphere.

Comment: With these things in mind, does 10 V 500 mA seem like too much?

Comment: Limit current to no more than rated current - a 20 W, 22 Ohm resistor on a moderate heat sink should do with a 10 V 5 VA transformer. I don't *think* 500 mA will heat up an AWG 18 copper conductor significantly: please find supporting data.

Comment: Alright, I’ll look for further data. Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: (Ordered a 25 W, 22 Ohm resistor because I can’t find any 20 W, 22 Ohm resistors in an aluminum housing, which I assume would be what acts as the heat sink, considering the fins. Hope it will still work…)

Comment: One more question… How did you get 10 V 500 mA? DC is very intuitive, but I am having trouble understanding what 10 V 5 VA means… I assume 10 V means the same thing it means with DC, but 5 VA is what, volt-amps? That converts to 500 mA? Or…? Sorry, I am extremely new to AC and I have essentially no understanding beyond how a single-phase generator physically works.

Comment: ChatGPT came through with an explanation. Dividing the power rating (5 VA) by the voltage (10 V) gives me the current (0.5 A) that the transformer can handle at the given voltage. 

Comment: VA is the unit for *apparent* power. *Real* power (W) / apparent power (VA) is the so called *power factor* - anywhere from 1 ("resistive load") to 0 ("reactive load"). GPT does not explain, answer, or understand. It reacts.

Comment: It reacted by answering and explaining. Not sure why that would be a sticking point for you. An answer and an explanation are both forms of reactions that GPT is capable of performing. But I do agree that it has no understanding.